# Multiple username/password for site

Tags: macos, firefox, keychain

I have a website which contains various pages and also a BulletinBoard.
I normally access this from OSX using Firefox, and store passwords in the Keychain using the "Keychain Services Integration" plugin.

This suggests the username and password for the whole website, which is OK for site administration.
Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to store the username and password for the BulletinBoard, so I have to manually enter it each time.

Can anyone suggest how I could have the BulletinBoard username and password suggested when it access .../BulletinBoard (or at least have this as one of the site addresses).

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing it to save the password with the [Remember Passwords](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/remember-passwords/) extension for Firefox.